# How can I get values from gruoped columns dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I started work with Python and have task with csv file.

I have a DataFrame object with multiple grouping also is sorting and aggregation. When I looping DataFrame object with .itertuples() I can get values from columns in DataFrame but cannot get from grouped columns('age_group', 'date'). How can I resolve this problem?

```
import pandas as pd
Data_Cov = pd.read_csv("Agreguoti_COVID19_atvejai_ir_mirtys.csv')
Aver_Day = Data_Cov[['date','age_gr','new_cases']]
Aver_Day_date_age = Aver_Day.groupby(['age_gr']).apply(lambda x: x.groupby('date') 
                                                       .sum('new_cases')
                                                       .sort_values('date', ascending=False))
for row in Aver_Day_date_age.itertuples():
      new_case = getattr(row,'new_cases')
      Start_date = getattr(row,'date')
#And there is error:
#AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Full error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\Covid_Spr.ipynb Cell 7' in <module>
      4 for row in Aver_Day_date_age.itertuples():
      5       new_case = getattr(row,'new_cases')
----> 6       Start_date = getattr(row,'date')

AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Data source (Aver_Day) look like this

```
             date         age_gr  new_cases  age_gr_ind   age_gr_new
0       2022-05-26            0-9          2           1         0-29
1       2022-05-26          20-29          2           1         0-29
2       2022-05-26          30-39          5           2        30-39
3       2022-05-26          40-49          5           3        40-49
4       2022-05-26          50-59          5           4        50-59
5       2022-05-26          60-69          2           5        60-69
6       2022-05-26          70-79          2           6        70-79
7       2022-05-26          80-89          0           7        80-89
8       2022-05-26          90-99          0           8        90-99
9       2022-05-25          10-19          2           1         0-29
10      2022-05-25          20-29          6           1         0-29
11      2022-05-25          30-39          3           2        30-39
12      2022-05-25          40-49          7           3        40-49
13      2022-05-25          50-59          2           4        50-59
14      2022-05-25          60-69          5           5        60-69
15      2022-05-25          70-79          0           6        70-79
16      2022-05-25          80-89          1           7        80-89
17      2022-05-25          90-99          1           8        90-99
18      2022-05-24            0-9          2           1         0-29
19      2022-05-24          10-19          2           1         0-29
20      2022-05-24          20-29          4           1         0-29
```

In this task in generally I will have to count new cases average of each day for the last fourteen days. I will have to work with nested loops.
There are about 300 000 rows in this file

Outpoot for this task look like this

```
date  age_gr_new  average
2020-10-01      0-29      24
2020-10-02      0-29      26
2020-10-03      0-29      21
2020-10-04      0-29      26
2020-10-05      0-29      25
2020-10-06      0-29      41
2020-10-07      0-29      17
2020-10-08      0-29      34
2020-10-09      0-29      43
2020-10-10      0-29      46
2020-10-11      0-29      27
2020-10-12      0-29      30
2020-10-13      0-29      59
2020-10-14      0-29      48
2020-10-15      0-29      62
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Show us an example of your desired output please.

Comment: For this subtask I need to get value of column 'date'

Comment: In this task in generally I will have to count new cases average of each day for the last fourteen days. There are about 300 000 rows in this file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.